# AngularJS NG-CSV files not downloading

Tags: angularjs, export-to-csv

I am fairly new to AngularJS, i am trying to generate .csv files from an Array using ng-csv.
Now i have tried everything but the files are not generated, i even tried the most simple example i could see on the internet. 
I do not see any errors in the error console but still no files are generated. 
I am working under windows with XAMPP.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="APP">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>angular-count-to example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .element{cursor:pointer;float:left;background-color:#ccc;padding:4px;}
    </style>

</head>
<body ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <p>{{data}}</p>
    <button type="button" ng-csv="data" filename="test.csv">Export</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/ng-csv/src/ng-csv/ng-csv.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('APP',["ngSanitize","ngCsv"]).
        controller('ExampleController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.filename = "test";
            $scope.data = [{a: 1, b:2}, {a:3, b:4}];       
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Above is the simplest example i tried, however even this is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try out a pure HTML5 Solution. This was a code block i did a while ago. Try customizing for yourself by excluding useless paramaters

```
function (JSONData, ReportTitle, ShowLabel, reportType, reportName) {
        //If JSONData is not an object then JSON.parse will parse the JSON string in an Object
        var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;

        angular.forEach(arrData, function (data, index) {
            if (data.date != undefined)
                data.date = dateFormat(data.date)
        });


        var CSV = '';
        //Set Report title in first row or line

        CSV += ReportTitle + '\r\n\n';

        //This condition will generate the Label/Header
        if (ShowLabel) {
            var row = "";

            //This loop will extract the label from 1st index of on array
            for (var index in arrData[0]) {
                row += index + ';';
            }

            row = row.slice(0, -1);

            //append Label row with line break
            CSV += row + '\r\n';
        }

        //1st loop is to extract each row
        for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
            var row = "";

            //2nd loop will extract each column and convert it in string comma-seprated
            for (var index in arrData[i]) {

                //var temp = arrData[i][index].toString().replace('.', ',');
                //arrData[i][index] = temp;

                row += '"' + arrData[i][index] + '";';
            }

            row = row.split('.').join(",");
            row.slice(0, row.length - 1);

            //add a line break after each row
            CSV += row + '\r\n';
        }

        if (CSV == '') {
            alert("Invalid data");
            return;
        }

        //Generate a file name
        var fileName = "MyReport_";
        //this will remove the blank-spaces from the title and replace it with an underscore
        fileName += ReportTitle.replace(/ /g, "_");

        //Initialize file format you want csv or xls
        var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);

        // Now the little tricky part.
        // you can use either>> window.open(uri);
        // but this will not work in some browsers
        // or you will not get the correct file extension

        //this trick will generate a temp <a /> tag
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = uri;

        //set the visibility hidden so it will not effect on your web-layout
        link.style = "visibility:hidden";
        link.download = fileName + ".csv";

        //this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    };
```

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that i could better do this in the backend with PHP. I have an array of milions of words i have to compute so this is to much for the frontend to handle. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: i do not think that is too much for the frontend. I suggest you test it before getting a conclusion

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are linking to the wrong ng-csv.js. The ng-csv.js file in the bower_components/ng-csv/src/ng-csv/ folder doesn't contain all of the code, you need to use the build version. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/ng-csv/build/ng-csv.js"></script>
```

Comment: @user2668026 Any luck?

Comment: sorry been very busy the last few weeks so i haven't tried it yet.
I will try it this weekend and report the outcome.